# Is FCP X 10.1.1 hanging because of older hardware?

Tags: upgrade, performance, mac-pro, final-cut-pro

I'm weighing the value of upgrading my machine because FCP X 10.1.1 is constantly hanging—more than once per 5 minutes—and I'm at a loss what to do. Is this just because I have older (Mid-2010) Xeon processors? Could there be other hardware issues contributing to this?

Choose your own adventure in answering my question:

- If I can get more life out of this machine, that would be great. In that case, please share any troubleshooting next steps.
- On the other hand, if I'm being unrealistic to try to keep this machine alive, convince me.

My projects are stored on the boot disk, an internal 3rd-party SSD. I'm running a high-powered albeit older machine with the latest version of FCP X and OS X. Hardware specs below.

The issue is sometimes concurrent with this error message from the Console: Final Cut Pro[3457]: *** OpenGL error 0x0506 (invalid framebuffer operation) in function "GL_CHECK_CURRENT_ERROR"

I've submitted feedback to Apple's development team.

Detailed system information:

Model Mac Pro Mid 2010
Processor  2 x 2.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon [8-Core]
Memory  16 GB 1066 MHz DDR3 ECC
Graphics  ATI Radeon HD 5770 1024 MB
Software  OS X 10.9.3
Storage Physical Drive:
  Media Name: Crucial_CT480M500SSD1 Media
  Medium Type: SSD
  Protocol: SATA
  Internal: Yes
  Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table)
  S.M.A.R.T. Status: Verified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my hardware is just fine. Upgrading to FCP X 10.1.2 solved the issue for me.

In case it helps the next person, here's Apple's troubleshooting steps for Final Cut Pro x 10.1 and beyond: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3893